# Help! How to solve this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

I've a problem with the following integral, can anybody help me? 
Thanks in advance.

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x\exp\left(\frac{x(2\rho\,y-x)}{2(1-\rho^{\,2}))}\right) dx
$$

Comment: [mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: chose a new variable, z say, so that the exponential just has a term like $exp(-z^2)$

Comment: What's the problem?  Complete the square the exponential and shift the origin.  The result will be a gaussian integral whose results are well known.

Answer (score 2):

Write

$$x(2\rho y - x) = (\rho y)^2 - (\rho y - x)^2 = \rho^2 y^2 - (x - \rho y)^2$$

so that

$$\exp\left(\frac{x(2\rho y - x)}{2(1 - \rho^2)}\right) = \exp\left(\frac{\rho^2 y^2}{2(1 - \rho^2)} - \frac{(x - \rho y)^2}{2(1 - \rho^2)}\right) = \exp\left(\frac{\rho^2 y^2}{2(1 - \rho^2)}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{(x - \rho y)^2}{2(1 - \rho^2)}\right).$$

Then

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\exp\left(\frac{(x - \rho y)^2}{2(1 - \rho^2)}\right)\, dx = \exp\left(\frac{\rho^2 y^2}{2(1 - \rho^2)}\right)\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\exp\left(-\frac{(x - \rho y)^2}{2(1 - \rho^2)}\right)\, dx.$$

By substitution $u = x - \rho y$, the last expression can be written

$$\exp\left(\frac{\rho^2 y^2}{2(1 - \rho^2)}\right) \int_{-\infty}^\infty (u + \rho y)\exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2(1 - \rho^2)}\right)\, du.$$

Either by direct computation or by a symmetry argument, we find that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty u \exp(-u^2/(2(1 - \rho^2))) = 0$. So our computation is reduced to

\begin{align}&\exp\left(\frac{\rho^2 y^2}{2(1 - \rho^2)}\right)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \rho y\exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2(1 - \rho^2)}\right)\, du \\
&= \rho y \exp\left(\frac{\rho^2 y^2}{2(1 - \rho^2)}\right)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2(1 - \rho^2)}\right)\, du\\
&= \rho y \exp\left(\frac{\rho^2 y^2}{2(1 - \rho^2)}\right) \times \sqrt{2\pi(1 - \rho^2)}\\
&= \rho y \sqrt{2\pi(1 - \rho^2)}\exp\left(\frac{\rho^2 y^2}{2(1 - \rho^2)}\right).
\end{align}

The second to the last line was obtained by recognizing the normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1 - \rho^2$. Thus

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(\frac{x(2\rho y - x)}{2(1 - \rho^2)}\right)\, dx = \rho y \sqrt{2\pi(1 - \rho^2)}\exp\left(\frac{\rho^2 y^2}{2(1 - \rho^2)}\right).$$